# Should I switch to BrE pronunciation?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

My English is American, and now I'm trying to switch to BrE. e.g. labour, favour etc. Recently, I learned that the word schedule has an Am.E and a Br.E pronunciation. Should I switch to the Br.E pronunciation?

Comment: It's your call. If you are trying to switch the spelling part, wouldn't it be better to also switch the pronunciation part? What's the point in being half way?

Comment: I guess, but I had doubts. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: The differences between American and British English go deeper than spelling and pronunciation; they also affect vocabulary, choice of expressions and less obvious aspects of usage. Switching over may result in inconsistency, unless you are still at an early stage and you can find a tutor or native speaker of British English to help you.

Comment: One word I can think of at the top of my head is truck vs. lorry.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you're trying to fool people into thinking you're British, I suspect this will be tricky, you'll make too many mistakes until you've had years of practice.

Comment: As Jay said, it would help to know the reasons you're trying to switch to BrE. Otherwise this just seems like an opinion poll.

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences in usage of words between BrE and AmE

> AmE = BrE
>   umbrella = brolly
>   elevator = lift
>   candy = sweets
>   OK = right
>   underwear = pants
>   like = fancy

It would depend on 1) how "far" want to go with BrE, 2) whether you want to "sound native", and 3) if you can pull off the accent.

One of the things Brits laugh at is that many Yanks sound like Dick van Dyke in *Mary Poppins* when they try to affect a British accent.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a Brit, there is nothing wrong with American English. Learn to speak (and write) English **well**, and forget about accent, regional spelling, etc.

If you want to be taken seriously, learn to avoid contractions such as *wanna*. In BrE, it would be words such as *innit* (isn't it).

By all means learn some BrE idioms if you like. Used judiciously, they can be very effective, *don't you know?* [mild sarcasm] (And they can also come in handy if you visit the UK.)